# QPSQL в Android

Tags: android, qt, postgresql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то собрать драйвер QPSQL для Андройд-проекта, находясь в Windows?
Уже несколько дней пытаюсь заставить приложение связываться с PostgreSQL, но ничего не выходит. Впервые занимаюсь чем-то подобным и уже начинаю думать, что это невозможно. Буду очень рад любому совету

Нашёл следующую [инструкцию](https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Qt_5_PostgreSQL_Plugin_for_Android), но, насколько я понимаю, внутри Windows проделать её не получится, а переносить все средства под linux очень не хочется, так как это может занять ещё пару дней, а в том, что что-то после этого получится, я совсем не уверен

Comment: при этом вот пример с mysql под ведроид  https://habr.com/ru/post/134502/

Answer (score 1):

Ну - можно заменить команду EXPORT для LINUXа командой SET, которая делает тоже самое для виндовса и попробовать собрать так, как написано в Вашей ссылке.
Так же надо заменить команду ./configure на configure.bat в Вашей инструкции
И всё - делаете тоже  самое, только для Windows.
Исходники постгреса и QT есть и для windows, и для LINUX, разницы нет, плюс ANDROID NDK тоже есть под windows.

Comment: там часто надо под конкретный qt подбирать конкретную версию NDK, я бы посоветовал сначала подобрать окружение, чтобы qt из исходников под windows собиралась, а потом уже в нём собрать драйвер

Comment: в windows даже есть команда SETX